# Why Observable declaration from array is not flatten?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

This is a question asked in the RXJS Gitter channel but no one answers it so I post it here, hoping to have an explanation.

> Hi everyone,
>
> I am a Java developer who tries to learn rxjs. I have a dumb question about an `Observable` declaration. To make my life easier I told myself that working with `Observable` is like working with the Java `Stream` api (even if  `Stream` is a pull base model).  The example that disturbes me is this one: In java I have
>
> ```
> Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
> Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.stream(intArray); // Here we have a stream of Integer not a Stream of Integer[], the array is flatten
> ```
>
> With rxjs if I do this:
>
> ```
> const intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> const intObs: Observable<number> = of(intArray); // The compiler complains, I have to change Observable<number> to Observable<number[]>
> ```
>
> It's a bit disturbing, why the `of(...)` method does not flat the array?
> Also, if we subscribe to an observable of `Observable<number[]>` why the received values are not of type `number[]` but of type `number`?
> I am a bit confused. Thanks for some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Java but in RxJS the generic type of Observable means what data type is this Observable going to emit (data type of each individual `next` emission). So `Observable<number>` means and Observable that emits only numbers. On the other hand `Observable<number[]>` means an Observable that emits arrays of numbers.

In RxJS `of()` only takes the value (or values) you pass as argument(s) and emits them as `next` emissions. It doesn't care what data type it is, no further logic is involved (what if you do want to emit an array of values `of([1, 2, 3])` and `of()` would keep flattenign them?).

In order to create an Observable from an array (an Observable that emits array items) you can use RxJS `from()` method:

```
from([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(...); // Will receive 3 `next` values.
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I want an `Observable` of array I should use `of(...)` and use `from` if I want the array to be flatten?

Comment: Yes. Technically, you could use `of(...array)` to expand individual emission but it makes more sence to use `from(array)`

Answer (score 3):

## RxJS # `of`

The RxJS `of` creation-operator takes a list of values and turns them into an Observable that emits that list and completes. It doesn't perform any checks/transformations for you.

This should work as expected:

```ts
const intObs: Observable<number> = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You can also use the spread operator to similar effect:

```ts
const intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const intObs: Observable<number> = of(...intArray);
```

---

## RxJS # `from`

Perahps a better solution is the RxJS `from` creation-operator which doesn't take values, but rather takes anything that's seen as an `ObservableInput` (Any `iterable`, `promise`, or `observable`). Actually, any ES6 Iterable, so `Arrays`, `Generators`, `Maps`, `HashMaps`, `Vectors`, custom iterables, you name it. They'll all work.

Since an array is an ES6 Iterable, the following should work:

```ts
const intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const intObs: Observable<number> = from(intArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, there is an error in the `of` part.

Comment: @akuma8 It compiles and works just fine for me, what error did you spot?

Comment: The error is here: 
`
const intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const intObs: Observable<number> = of(intArray); // it should be const intObs: Observable<number[]>
`

Comment: Otherwise we have `TS2322: Type 'Observable<number[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.   Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: You need to destructure the array into a list as mentioned. The list is then made up of numbers, there's no more array of numbers. This is why I said "you can use the spread operator to similar effect." It's not an error, look closely please, it needs to be written as `of(...intArray)`

Comment: I didn't know that notation `of(...intArray)`, what's that? I should do less Java and more JS/TypeScript

Comment: :) Just look up `destructuring` for the abstract thing, or the spread operator for how `...` works. For example `const [head, ...tail] = [1,2,3,4]` will leave you with two variables such that `head = 1` and `tail = [2,3,4]`. You can even generate new lists. `const double = [...intArray, ...intArray]` means that `double = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: It's awesome! As a backend developer I spend more time with Java but the JS/TS flexibility makes me want to learn more.